# Wordpress plugins not appearing in admin

Tags: wordpress

I am using Ubuntu and installed wordpress via:

`sudo apt-get install wordpress`

This installed wordpress to /usr/share/wordpress. When I go to the admin and view installed plugins,  `Akismet` plugin displays. But if I download a plugin and place it in /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins directory (even after trying `chmod 777 plugin-dir`),  the plugin doesn't show in the admin. If I remove the `Akismet` plugin, it disappears from the admin and reappears after replacing it.  So, not sure why that default plugin is being found in the `wp-content/plugins` directory yet no other plugin seems to work.

**Edit**

Only plugin files that are inside the directory wp-content/plugins/akismet are notice by the wordpress installation.  Why would that be?  How can I fix that?

Comment: You have tried chmod 777, have you also checked the owner (chown)?

Comment: yeah the ownership is set to the same (www-data) recursively.

Comment: There is a Wordpress Stack Exchange. Maybe this question belongs there. But I answered here, nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

This is nicely explained in a document that is installed with the same Debian package: `/usr/share/doc/wordpress/README.Debian.gz`

In short, most Wordpress sources are installed to `/usr/share/wordpress`, belonging to `root`, but by default Wordpress is configured to look for content under `/var/lib/wordpress`. That directory tree should be owned by your web server's user (usually, `apache` for Apache, `www-data` for Nginx).

```
$ sudo chown -R /var/lib/wordpress
```

**Notice that core plugins and themes** are symlinked from `/var/lib/wordpress` to `/usr/share/wordpress`, so they actually are under ownership of root.

Akismet is one of those core plugins; it is installed as a symlink.

```
$ ls /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/
akismet -> /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/akismet/
```

That is why other plugins are only found after moving them into the same folder: they are found by the Wordpress installation through the symlink.

Do not install plugins under `/usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins`, but under `/var/lib/wordpress/wp-content/plugins`.